# A strange UITableView crash : NSRangeException

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have encountered a strange crash on my code.

Here's the code :

```
UIView *tableHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView;
CGRect frame = tableHeaderView.frame;
frame.size.height = 0;
tableHeaderView.frame = frame;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView;
```

The crash occurred on the last line of the code.

And, here is the log

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 
'*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x345ae2a3 0x3c25397f 0x344f9b75 0x1a7055 0x363ebb8f 0x363d702b 0x363d7599 0x363d740d 0x3642b22b 0x1a0d77 0x363d5595 0x3642a14b 0x3642a091 0x36429f75 0x36429e99 0x364295d9 0x364294c1 0x364764d1 0x36428861 0x36428713 0x364a4399 0x364508fb 0x36691619 0x364a39b9 0x364a1fe7 0x26c8a1 0x221997 0x34ee96fd 0x34e291f9 0x34e29115 0x3428b45f 0x3428ab43 0x342b2fcb 0x344f474d 0x342b342b 0x3421703d 0x34583683 0x34582ee9 0x34581cb7 0x344f4ebd 0x344f4d49 0x380b82eb 0x3640a301 0x10819f 0x3c68ab20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I really don't have any idea what happened on my code.

Any advice are helpful for me!

Thank you.

Comment: Code provide above is not the cause of  this exception.

Comment: Place some NSLogs in cellforrow and viewforheader methods to find where exactly the crash is.

Comment: Can you paste the cellforRowAtIndexpath method code or just check whether the array you are passing to the tableview is empty or having some data?

Comment: Thanks @Ernaidu. There was a fault on cellForRowAtindexPath when the count of Key array is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely initialise some array in your class firstly check your array by placing NSLog that it should have some value or it is null. I think it is null thats why they creating a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the headerView for a table, this is the proper way to do it:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:kHeaderFrame];
     return headerView;
}
```

Comment: @DuricanRadhu In his question he want to set "tableHeaderView", not each section header view.